# Dynamic SQl throwing conversion issue with datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

The below code throwing 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'. Here i am trying to from some Dynamic SQL

```
  DECLARE @TODELETEDATE DATETIME
  BEGIN
    SET @TODELETEDATE =GETDATE()-5

    PRINT '<' +  @TODELETEDATE 
 END
```

Comment: convert(nvarchar(44) ,  @TODELETEDATE )

Comment: You'll need to `CONVERT` or `CAST` `@TODELETEDATE` to a string data type (`NVARCHAR` or similar) if you want to print it

Comment: You should be using DATEADD instead of getdate() - 5. It is a shortcut that doesn't work on all date datatypes.

Comment: Also: `GETDATE() - 5` is very ambiguous - you're subracting 5 ***what*** from the current date - Days? Months? Years? Hours? Minutes? ... I'd **never** allow any of my programmers to use this syntax - it's just too unclear - use `DATEADD()` to make it **clear** what you intend to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are concatenating datetime value to a string that's why it is failing.

```
DECLARE @TODELETEDATE DATETIME
  BEGIN
    SET @TODELETEDATE =GETDATE()-5

    PRINT '<' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@TODELETEDATE ,120)
 END
```